# event.preventDefault() doesn't work with form submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

the `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="vue.js"></script>

 <div id="app">
 <form v-on:submit.prevent="saveData">
 <input type="text" name="test">
 <button type="submit">Go</button>
 </form>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
 'el': '#app',
      'methods':{
         'saveData': function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
  }
  }
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Works for me. What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.prevent` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) is sufficient. You don't have to call `event.preventDefault()` inside the handler.

See demo below. There are two forms, one with `.prevent` and one without. Notice the first just logs. The second logs and goes to another page (the form submits).

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="saveData">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <form v-on:submit="saveData">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <button type="submit">I WONT PREVENT</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({
    'el': '#app',
    'methods': {
      'saveData': function(event) {
        console.log('I was called');
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```